# How to recount rows in the first column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I want to drop some rows, and I've found a fairly elegant way to do this:

```
Df2=Df[-c(1,2,11),]
```

however, when I call the data with the head() function, I notice that in the 1st column the rows start from 3,4,5, etc

I also notice that if I export my data into csv and import it again, there is the old column (starting from 3) and a new one appears as well (starting from 1,2,3) which I find redundant.

Is there any way I can tell R to recount the rows of the old column before saving it?

Comment: How about `rownames(Df2) = 1:nrow(Df2)` before saving? Also, what code do you use to reload the data?

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly, thank you. I use this code to reload: `Df2=read.csv2(file="D.csv", header=T)`

Comment: `rownames(Df2) <- NULL` will reset them.  Or you could do `Df2 <- data.frame(Df[-c(1,2,11),], row.names = NULL)`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the answers given by Vandenman and Rich Scriven:

Either

```
rownames(Df2) = 1:nrow(Df2) 
row.names(Df2) = 1:nrow(Df2)
```

or

```
rownames(Df2) <- NULL
row.names(Df2) <- NULL
```

or

```
Df2 <- data.frame(Df2, row.names = NULL)
Df2 <- as.data.frame(Df2, row.names = NULL)
```

will do the job